# SimpleForm w. Bootstrap - Input changes to "form-inline" when setting "html5: true"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a time based input that I'd like to display as one input vs. two default selects boxes. I found the solution to this was to add `html: true` to my input. Unfortunately this changes the input's parent container class from `form-control` to `form-inline`. Is there a way to change this from within SimpleForm without explicitly giving it the class in the html options hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to simple_form_bootstrap.rb and check this snip

```rb
config.wrappers :multi_select, tag: :div, class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-danger' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: :div, class: 'form-inline' do |ba|
        ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'
        ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :div, class: 'invalid-feedback' }
        ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :small, class: 'form-text text-muted' }
    end
end
```

there is the form-inline you are looking for, notice that the default wrapper for time and dates is multi_select

```rb
config.wrapper_mappings = {
    check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :horizontal_file_input,
    boolean: :horizontal_boolean,
    datetime: :multi_select,
    date: :multi_select,
    time: :multi_select
}
```

Comment: by the way, this is one of my configurations so there might be some differences.

Comment: Mine does in fact look the same. Would I simply remove the key/value pair from the hash or is there a value that would have it display as just an input?

Comment: you could change form-inline to the one you want and keep de html true option or create a custom wrapper and set it with something like `f.input :date, wrapper: :my_custom_wrapper`

Comment: Right on. Thanks!